# Difference between Entity bean and Entity class?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

What are the differences between `entity beans` which are in the `EJB 2.0` specification and `entity classes` which in the `3.0` specification?

Answer (score 1):

In EJB 2, entity was a bean meaning that it had to live in a container and need to be managed (similar to other beans, say stateful, stateless, message driven beans).

However in EBJ 3.x, entity is a POJO class - meaning that it can live outside container also.. plain java application can make use of entities as ORM layer with any providers supporting it..